# Is this a bug or normal: Money - SqlDataReader vs OleDbDataReader

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, ado.net

We recently received complaints that amounts started to show with 4 decimals in the end, like `1.2300` instead of `1.23`, with Sql Server DB. Our app is not perfect - by day's end it simply calls

```
Convert.ToString(reader("field"))
```

But before we used `OleDb` provider directly, and few years back we started to use abstract provider that behind scenes uses `SqlClient` or `ODP.NET` based on connection settings.

Here is what happening when calling `Convert.ToString(reader("field"))`

**OleDB**

> DB field is Decimal - reader data type is `decimal` and return is `1.0000`
>   DB field is Money - reader data type is `decimal` and return is **`1.00` <--**

**SqlClient**

> DB field is Decimal - reader data type is `decimal` and return is `1.0000`
>  
>   DB field is Money - reader data type is `decimal` and return is **`1.0000` <--**

The application is >10yo and the whole thing, as far as I can tell, was invested into fact that field *Money* returns `0.00` and field *Decimal* returns whatever precision.

But I am wondering if that is some kind of unintentional behavior? Unless I find genius solution, fixing this globally in rather large code base may take some remarkable effort.

Comment: I wouldn't rely on the standard format strings, you can't just pass one to `ToString`?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I wouldn't write code like this - this is old stuff. My code would be based on metadata. And funny part is - we have metadata but all conversions were written using ..... `ToString/datatype.Parse` - amaizing. That's not the question here

Comment: @Plutonix My true option is to use `GetProviderSpecificFieldType/GetProviderSpecificValue`. I can create extension and ... But boy, this will be a lot of work to identify places. See, this is one place where it takes any datatype and `ToString`s it. This is was "genius" decision to keep all field values in form of string.

Comment: The number of digits to the right of the decimal mark returned from the `Decimal.ToString` method is controlled by the _scale_ component of `System.Decimal` (see: [Decimal Constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb1c1a6x(v=vs.110).aspx). The scale value of the returned System.Decimal is set by the _scale_ parameter of the SQL Decimal type (i.e decimal(18, 2) has a scale of 2).  The [Money Sql Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179882(v=sql.105).aspx) has a scale of 4.  It is possible create a new `Decimal` value with the desired scale via multiplication or division.

Comment: @TnTinMn Look, reader returns decimal in both providers. And DB field is exactly same - money, scale = 4. Only with OleDb and SqlClient, `ToString/Convert.ToString` return different results.

Answer (score 0):

Relying on default formatting for a type is shortsighted at best and should be avoided in favor of specifying a specific format.

The `ToString` method for `System.Decimal`uses its scale factor to determine the number of digits shown to the right of the decimal mark.  It is possible to set the scale factor in the constructor using the overload: [`Decimal Constructor (Int32, Int32, Int32, Boolean, Byte)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb1c1a6x(v=vs.110).aspx).

The SQL Server [`money`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179882(v=sql.105).aspx) type is read by .Net as a `System.Decimal`.  The SQLClient provider sets the type's internal scale to 4.  In my testing, the OLE DB Provider in SQL Server Native Client sets the scale based on the retrieved value and the scale can range from 0 to 4.

For the purposes of this answer, assume a table with this schema.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestSQLD_M](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [D2] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [D4] [decimal](18, 4) NULL,
    [M] [money] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TestSQLD_M] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

`D2.ToString` would yield: #.##

`D4.ToString` would yield: #.####

`M.ToString` would yield: # or #.# or #.### or #.#### depend on the value of `M`

To force `M` to have a default format of `#.##`, you can cast the value to a `SQL decimal` with the required scale factor in `Select` clause. So instead of:

`Select ID, D2, D4, M From TestSQLD_M`

use:

`Select ID, D2, D4, Cast(M As decimal(18,2)) As M From TestSQLD_M`

This will produce the same format using either `SQLClient` or `OLE DB Provider in SQL Server Native Client`.